# Howto Allow GZIP for Azure Table Storage Queries

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I found when query Azure Table Storage, the payload does not gzip in transfer.

here is the headers checked by fiddler

**Send:**

```
GET http://account.table.core.windows.net/sometable() HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
DataServiceVersion: 2.0;NetFx
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0;NetFx
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18
x-ms-date: Mon, 13 Aug 2012 02:23:48 GMT
Authorization: SharedKeyLite xxxxxxxxxxxxx=
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/xml
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Host: account.table.core.windows.net
```

**Receive**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8
Server: Windows-Azure-Table/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 254e470e-c50d-409b-8429-3d5bc9beabaa
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18
Date: Mon, 13 Aug 2012 02:23:37 GMT
Content-Length: 168553
```

The xml content which length 168K, if gzipped, only around 40k, so, my question is: where and how can I allow gzip for Azure table queries?

Comment: Route the requests through nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Windows Azure storage supports compression.

Comment: Why? Is there a plan for it? Except slow, also cost more.

Comment: I don't know the answers to your follow-up questions.